# How to map static columns differently from other columns?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-java-driver

How can I map [the example given here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql-in-2-0-6) to the below class, using datastax Java object mapping?

```
public class User {
    private int user;
    private int balance;

    private List<Bill> bills;
}

public class Bill {
    private String description;
    private int amount;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regards to the mapping module in the java-driver, a static column does not need to be treated any differently then a non-static column.  One concern you will have though is you want some consistency in that the balance is updated only if it is an expected value, so using the Mapper's save method alone will not be adequate.  Rather you will do a batch with a conditional update of the balance, and an update with the expense in the same batch.

To make this convenient and still make use of the Mapper, you could use an [Accessor-annotated interface](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/common/drivers/reference/accessorAnnotatedInterfaces.html) to define your queries and map them back to your objects.  You can then create a data access object for interfacing with Cassandra using your mapper object and some other methods.

This will take some work, but I think it provides you a nice clean way to abstract your solution away from Cassandra while still using it in an idiomatic way.  Another option is look into [Achilles](https://github.com/doanduyhai/Achilles) which is a more advanced object persistence manager for Cassandra.  [Kundera](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera) and [Spring Data](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra.git) are other possible options.

First, lets look at your classes and map them to the table defined in the example from the blog:

```
  CREATE TABLE bills (
     user text,
     balance int static,
     expense_id int,
     amount int,
     description text,
     paid boolean,
     PRIMARY KEY (user, expense_id)
  );
```

From your example, I suspect that you may wish to use an User-defined type instead of separate columns for a bill,  but since you tagged this post 'cassandra-2.0' and UDTs are not introduced until 2.1, I will not cover this, but if you'd like me to expound more on that I can.

Lets define our class `Bill`:

```java
@Table(name="bills")
public class Bill {

    @PartitionKey
    private String user;

    private int balance;

    @ClusteringColumn
    @Column(name="expense_id")
    private int expenseId;

    private int amount;

    private String description;

    private boolean paid;

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(int balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public int getExpenseId() {
        return expenseId;
    }

    public void setExpenseId(int expenseId) {
        this.expenseId = expenseId;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public boolean isPaid() {
        return paid;
    }

    public void setPaid(boolean paid) {
        this.paid = paid;
    }
}
```

Lets also define a `BillAccessor` for interacting with our Bills in cassandra mapping them back to `Bill` objects.  This should cover all queries from the blog post:

```java
@Accessor
public interface BillAccessor {

    @Query("INSERT INTO bills (user, balance) VALUES (?, ?) IF NOT EXISTS")
    BoundStatement addUser(String user, int balance);

    @Query("UPDATE bills SET balance = :newBalance WHERE user = :user IF balance = :currentBalance")
    BoundStatement updateBalance(@Param("user") String user, @Param("currentBalance") int currentBalance,
                            @Param("newBalance") int newBalance);

    @Query("SELECT balance from bills where user=?")
    ResultSet getBalance(String user);

    @Query("INSERT INTO bills (user, expense_id, amount, description, paid) values (?, ?, ?, ?, false) IF NOT EXISTS")
    BoundStatement addBill(String user, int expenseId, int amount, String description);

    @Query("UPDATE bills set paid=true where user=? and expense_id=? IF paid=false")
    BoundStatement markBillPaid(String user, int expenseId);

    @Query("SELECT * from bills where user=?")
    Result<Bill> getBills(String user);
}
```

Next we'll create a DAO for interfacing with your bills using the `Bill` class and `BillAccessor`:

```java
public class BillDao {

    private final Session session;

    private final Mapper<Bill> mapper;

    private final BillAccessor accessor;

    public BillDao(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
        MappingManager manager = new MappingManager(session);
        this.mapper = manager.mapper(Bill.class);
        this.accessor = manager.createAccessor(BillAccessor.class);
    }

    public Integer getBalance(String user) {
        ResultSet result = accessor.getBalance(user);
        Row row = result.one();
        if(row == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return row.getInt(0);
        }
    }

    public Iterable<Bill> getBills(String user) {
        return accessor.getBills(user);
    }

    public Bill getBill(String user, int expenseId) {
        return mapper.get(user, expenseId);
    }

    public int addBill(String user, int expenseId, int amount, String description) throws UpdateException {
        BatchStatement batch = new BatchStatement();

        Integer balance = getBalance(user);
        if (balance == null) {
            balance = 0;
            // we need to create the user.
            batch.add(accessor.addUser(user, balance - amount));
        } else {
            // we need to update the users balance.
            batch.add(accessor.updateBalance(user, balance, balance - amount));
        }
        batch.add(accessor.addBill(user, expenseId, amount, description));
        ResultSet result = session.execute(batch);

        if (result.wasApplied()) {
            return balance - amount;
        } else {
            throw new UpdateException("Failed applying bill, conditional update failed.");
        }
    }

    public int payForBill(Bill bill) throws UpdateException {
        Integer balance = getBalance(bill.getUser());
        if(balance == null) {
            throw new UpdateException("Failed paying for bill, user doesn't exist!");
        }
        BatchStatement batch = new BatchStatement();
        batch.add(accessor.updateBalance(bill.getUser(), balance, bill.getAmount() + balance));
        batch.add(accessor.markBillPaid(bill.getUser(), bill.getExpenseId()));

        ResultSet result = session.execute(batch);

        if(result.wasApplied()) {
            return bill.getAmount() + balance;
        } else {
            throw new UpdateException("Failed paying for bill, conditional update failed.");
        }
    }

    public class UpdateException extends Exception {
        public UpdateException(String msg) {
            super(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that we check whether or not a change was applied by checking [ResultSet.wasApplied()](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/ResultSet.html#wasApplied()).  Since we are doing conditional updates, the change may not be applied if our conditions do not hold.  The DAO will simply throw an `UpdateException` if the change wasn't applied, but you could choose a different strategy like retrying an arbitrary number of times in the DAO.

Finally lets write some code to exercise the DAO:

```java
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build();
try {
    Session session = cluster.connect("readtest");
    BillDao billDao = new BillDao(session);

    String user = "chandru";

    // Create a bill, should exercise user create logic.
    int balance = billDao.addBill(user, 1, 10, "Sandwich");
    System.out.format("Bill %s/%d created, current balance is %d.%n", user, 1, balance);

    // Create another bill, should exercise balance update logic.
    balance = billDao.addBill(user, 2, 6, "Salad");
    System.out.format("Bill %s/%d created, current balance is %d.%n", user, 2, balance);

    // Pay for all the bills!
    for(Bill bill : billDao.getBills(user)) {
        balance = billDao.payForBill(bill);
        System.out.format("Paid for %s/%d, current balance is %d.%n", user, bill.getExpenseId(), balance);

        // Ensure bill was paid.
        Bill newBill = billDao.getBill(user, bill.getExpenseId());
        System.out.format("Is %s/%d paid for?: %b.%n", user, newBill.getExpenseId(), newBill.isPaid());
    }

    // Try to add another bill with an already used expense id.
    try {
        billDao.addBill(user, 1, 1, "Diet Coke");
    } catch(BillDao.UpdateException ex) {
        System.err.format("Could not add bill %s/%d: %s", user, 1, ex.getMessage());
    }

} finally {
    cluster.close();
}
```

If all goes well, you should observe the following output:

```
Bill chandru/1 created, current balance is -10.
Bill chandru/2 created, current balance is -16.
Paid for chandru/1, current balance is -6.
Is chandru/1 paid for?: true.
Paid for chandru/2, current balance is 0.
Is chandru/2 paid for?: true.
Could not add bill chandru/1: Failed applying bill, conditional update failed.
```

And the state of your table will be:

```
cqlsh:readtest> select * from bills;

 user    | expense_id | balance | amount | description | paid
---------+------------+---------+--------+-------------+------
 chandru |          1 |       0 |     10 |    Sandwich | True
 chandru |          2 |       0 |      6 |       Salad | True
```

Comment: That approach flattens out the type. The fact that balance is not associated with individual bills is represented appropriated in this approach. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: I may not be understanding your question in full.  A static column is represented across the entire partition (all rows sharing a user).  Do you want to be able to represent a bill separately from the user and balance information?  In that case you have 2 choices: 1. Represent individual bill information as a User Defined Type (2.1+ only: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/cqlUseUDT.html).  2. Create a separate class that you can map from the Bill object in BillingDao.  Option 1 is handled for you by the mapper, where Option 2 requires work in the client code.

Comment: You could also use UDTs have one single row per user that has List<Bill>. UDTs require 2.1 and you tagged the post 'cassandra-2.0' so I refrained from answering the question with a 2.1-specific answer.  I can update my answer to reflect that though.

Comment: Just to add another note, I'd discourage using List<Bill> since you plan on updating Bills to mark them as paid, whenever you do this you will need to know the position of the Bill in the List to update.  You could use Map<int,Bill> and map the Bill to it's expense_id, but I think it would be better off using an approach where each Bill is a row within a User partition.